# How to check if a PHP string is different than meta field?

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

I have a function that strips an mp3 link from `the_content` and saves it a custom field called `audio_url` and then removes the mp3 link from the `the_content`. What I need help with is if the `the_content` has a new mp3 link and the custom field needs to be updated with the new mp3 link. I've tried so many options that it either won't update or it deletes the data written in the custom field

My function code:

```
function save_url_link( $post_id, $post ){
// only works if the post is an audio post format
if ( has_post_format('audio', $post_id)) {
// look for either http or https mp3, m4a, ogg, wav or wma files
$pattern = "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/";
// php the removes all except the mp3 link
preg_match_all($pattern,$post->post_content,$matches);
// saves the mp3 link to a string
$audio_raw = $matches[0][0];
// check if meta field is empty
if (get_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', true ) == '') {
  // update the meta field
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $audio_raw ); 
  // removes the save action
  remove_action('save_post', 'save_url_link', 10, 2);
  // update the content without the mp3 link
  wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id,'post_excerpt'=>$audio_raw,'post_content' => preg_replace('/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/', "", $post->post_content)));  
// close and save
};}}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_url_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it deleted the value when you had no URL in the content, so $audio_raw was empty.

```
if ($audio_raw && get_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', true ) != $audio_raw) {
  // update the meta field
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $audio_raw ); 
}
```

checks that $audio_raw isn't false/null/empty and that $audio_raw isn't the same as the string currently in `audio_url`.

BTW, I'm pretty sure

```
remove_action('save_post', 'save_url_link', 10, 2);
```

Doesn't really to anything, since you're already in that hook when you're removing the hook from `save_post`. It won't run twice, so no need to remove it.

Comment: I added the `remove_action` because I have having time-out issues and that fixed it.

Comment: That's strange, but hey, whatever works! Does the audio_url-update work for you?